# Accessing hidden appdata in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, minecraft, appdata, hidden-files

So, this may have an obvious answer, but I couldn't find anything on it so I figured I'd just try asking. Basically, I was using a free Minecraft server host called "Aternos" to work on a server before paying for the actual one. I didn't realize that I wouldn't be able to download the plugin data, and now I will lose months of work if I can't somehow access it.

When saving backups, they save them to a hidden appdata folder in Google Drive, I couldn't seem to find a way to access this folder at all.

My question is; is there any possible way to access this folder and download the data, so that I can use it on a new (paid) server.

Thanks!

Comment: Already read through that and unless I misread it does not, thank you though.

Comment: May I ask what method you are using to try and search for the hidden app data? From what I know, you may only do it programmatically based on the [Store application-specific data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata).

Comment: I haven’t tried to search it yet because I honestly have no idea how to do that, the other question you had linked seemed to be a solution for android and I’m on windows 10.

Comment: Why not just download it? https://aternos.org/worlds

Comment: That only downloads the world, not the plugin data.

Answer (score 1):

They way the app data folder works is that it files are created they are linked to the application that created them. Using the client id for the app.

[Store application-specific data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata)

> Use this folder to store any files that the user shouldn't directly interact with. This folder is only accessible by your application and its contents are hidden from the user and from other Drive apps.

The feature that makes app data most secure is that.

1. The user cant access the data.
2. Other applications cant access the data.

Only the project that created the data is able to access it.  So the only way for you to access that data is though the project that created it.